# advice for data retireval from SD card

Tags: windows, audio, data-recovery, sd-card, file-recovery

Hoping to retrieve data from an SD card. Our story so far:

Inserted a 4GB SD card into a USB reader on a Win10 PC. The computer saw a directory prefaced by a dot (*.Spotlight100*), which contained the two sound recordings I made yesterday (Zed001.WAV, my test recording, was 20 MB; Zed002.WAV, the real content, was 450 MB).

Computer couldn't open or copy Zed002.WAV, so the first thing I did was change the directory name (to **max**), in case it didn't like that dot-prefix directory. Changing the directory name made no difference.

Next think I did was run chkdsk on the SD card; this process was successful, but Zed002.WAV is now 311MB. Opening it, I can see that it has a good quality recording of the first hour of content.

So right now I'm freezing. The SD card is still mounted. Hoping for advice of good solutions to rescue any data that might still be floating around on this card.

Comment: .Spotlight-V100 is an Apple search index structure. It doesn't contain your audio file, only attributes to make searching faster. I'm not sure how you even magaged to decipher an actual file name in there - that's really not what is stored in that folder, it's mainly things like sql databases, truly esoteric stuff you really don't need to get your hands dirty in.

Comment: BTW, never run chkdsk on a drive you think may be failing **if you need the data from the drive**. chkdsk's job is to fix the file structure, which it will do at the expense of any and all data, if necessary. It's job is not to find broken files, just to fix the directory. Many people discover that too late.